# Joins on MySQL many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, many-to-many

This has been driving me mad.

I have three tables:

```
items
  ID
  name
  type

cats
  ID
  name

items_to_cats
  FK_ITEM_ID
  FK_CAT_ID
```

This is a simple many-to-many relationship. I have items and categories. Each item can be linked to one or more categories. This is done via a simple joining table where each row maintains a relationship between one item and one category using foreign key constraints.

You will notice that my "items" table has a field called "type". This is an indexed column that defines the type of content stored there. Example values here are "report", "interview", "opinion", etc.

Here's the question. **I want to retrieve a list of categories that have at least one item of type "report"**.

Ideally I want to get the result in a single query using joins. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct cats.id, cats.name
from cats
join items_to_cats on items_to_cats.fk_cat_id=cats.id
join items on items.id=items_to_cats.fk_item_id
where items.type='report'
```

Just as a point of database design, if you have a small set of legal values for items.type, i.e. "report", "interview", "opinion", maybe a couple more, then you really should create a separate table for that with, say, an id and a name, then just put the type id in the items table. That way you don't get into trouble because somewhere it's mis-spelled "raport", or even more likely, someone puts "reports" instead of "report".

Comment: A perfect, simple, beautiful solution. Thanks muchly Jay!

Comment: You can also the an enum field, here the type will only accept the values previously set for it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

or how about this :

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM cats c
WHERE c.id IN 
    (SELECT ic.fk_cat_id 
     FROM items_to_cats ic 
     JOIN items i on i.id=ic.fk_item_id 
     WHERE items.type='report'
    )
```

Comment: Works perfectly also, thanks Kevin. If you're interested, Jay's double-join solution is actually a little faster, but I've tested both queries on only a very small data so far!

Comment: interesting, I would not have thought there was much in it, I guess that is why it is so important to look at the query plans and understand the underlying data.

Comment: Embedded queries are usually slower than joins. I recall reading in the Oracle documentation once that Oracle attempts to "flatten" embedded queries into joins when it can for performance reasons. But it's good to see two solutions: it may give you ideas for how to solve other query questions.

Comment: Im not sure that is true, I would expect the driving sub-query to be evaluated first, as long as it has a relatively small result set it should be quicker, as the database should realize the fk returned is being used to query the pk .(i'm assuming fk's and type are all indexed)....I do not have mysql here now I'll check later.

Comment: Did a little bit of testing, With 200k items & 90k items_to_cats, (with all tables analyzed and an equal spread of data with all columns indexed) I found the 2 queries to take exactly the same amount of time in MYSQL & Oracle. However in Oracle the query plan reported the query cost to be roughly 3 times better, (The DISTINCT was causing extra work).